# in-store delivery method is still not displayed

Tags: code

I have followed all the steps in the guideline URL "https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/shipping/shipping-in-store-delivery.html" but the in-store delivery method is still not displayed in the frontend. I am using version 2.4.2

Comment: Did you properly selected the store view? Store / configuration / Sales then Main website and default store views at the top left hand corner. Please remember to complete shipping settings. Products shall also be completed with size and weight to get the calculation.

Comment: does you created source in MSI? and assigned to stock?

Comment: Yes, i do  all setting related to "shipping settings"  "Adding a New Source" , "Configuring Distance Priority Algorithm." and  assigned to stock.